# How to dynamically change document title in JS, so WeChat browser will detect it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, title, wechat

I have a webapp written in .js (no jQuery) that changes document title depending on what's currently visible on the screen. That works great on desktop and mobile browsers, except it does not in WeChat browser under iOS (haven't tested in WeChat on Android yet though).

Basic document title change code:

```
MyNamespace.setDocTitle = function(v)
{
    document.title = v;
}
```

iOS Safari, Android Chrome, and desktop browsers of course all will reflect change of title. However, when this webapp is loaded in WeChat, it shows only title that is set in html header.

I've tried not to set  tag in header at all, but in that case, WeChat shows no title at all.

If anyone has experience with WeChat and can tell me if there is a way to make it recognise dynamically changed document title (without breaking entire webapp into separate html files which is really last resort option if nothing else works...), I would appreciate it!

When checking navigator info, on iOS it uses Safari. However, it does not have 100% same behaviour as same stand-alone browser...

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.**

I have tested it on WeChat on Android and it worked. So issue is on WeChat on iOS only.

I suspect that it's a bug in WeChat for iOS, but if anyone may have some workaround, would be great to know!

Answer (score 1):

For the future generations:

```
window.title = '...';
// ...
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = "none";
// load anything small from your domain
iframe.setAttribute("src", "//example.com/favicon.ico");
var _l = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        iframe.removeEventListener('load', _l);
        document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    });
};
iframe.addEventListener('load', _l);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

This will trigger document re-evaluation and a new title will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this [JS-SDK](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=JS_SDK_DOCUMENT) thing officially released by Wechat.

You load the js file on the page you want to open in wechat app, and config it with your appid and signature, then you can use API in your js like this:

`wx.onMenuShareTimeline({
    title: '', // Sharing title
    link: '', // Sharing link
    imgUrl: '', // Sharing image URL
    success: function () { 
        // Callback function executed after a user confirms sharing
    },
    cancel: function () { 
        // Callback function executed after a user cancels sharing
    }
});`

We have used this strategy to dynamically customize our webviews sharing actions since this SDK released, works really well.

Comment: This is not answer to my question :-) I am fully aware of WeChat JavaScript API - and what you have described above is setting a sharing title. Nothing to do with my question above... I am changing document title dynamically, so when user is seeing different content within same webapp, title will change.

Comment: To clarify: document title is shown in the center of the top tab of WeChat. This title is initially loaded from <title>....</title> header tag, however can be dynamically changed using javascript - in all browsers. But, unfortunately, WeChat on iOS does not updates it if changes in javascript. I can confirm that I have tested it on Android WeChat and it worked there.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).prop('title', 'test');
```

or

```
document.title = 'test';
```

Comment: The question specifically says "no Jquery".

Comment: @Sebin Simon, thanks for quick answer but I've clearly stated that I use document.title = something, and that it does not work in WeChat on iOS and that I'm looking for a solution that will trick WeChat into updating document title.